# Issue while updating from angular 4 to 6 version

Tags: angular

I am updating my current project from angular 4 version to 6. I followed the steps mentioned in this URL: https://update.angular.io/

I am trying to update my angualr packages  using command **ng update --all --next --force** . I get the following error:-

[error image on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYjrS.png)

Comment: Please add your error as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that log file(C:\users\Md.jawaid\appData\roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018....debug.log) after run that ng update command (or) Use npm cache clean command